# How do I get hrefs from hrefs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I get hrefs from hrefs using Python in class and method format?
I have tried:

```
root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'

class IEAData:
       def __init__(self):
             try:--
             except:


       def get_links(self, url):
            all_links = []
            page = requests.get(root_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
               all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
            return all_links
            #print(all_links)

iea_obj = IEAData()
yearLinks = iea_obj.get_links(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')

reportLinks = []

for url in yearLinks:
    links =iea_obj.get_links(yearLinks)
    print(links)
```

Recommended: links variable must have all month hrefs but not getting, so please tell me how I should do it.

Comment: What's the issue here? Are you getting errors? If so, which ones? What I can see right away is that you're calling `iea_obj.get_links(yearLinks)` in your last loop, where `yearLinks` is a list, but the function expects its argument to be a string. I think you meant to do `links =iea_obj.get_links(url)`.

Comment: In class and method format of python i need to parse all links, which is present in the hrefs i.e if you hit years href then you get months href , but in the class and method format

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with your code. Your `get_links()` function was not using the `url` that was passed to it. When looping over the returned links, you were passing `yearLinks` rather than the `url`.

The following should get you going:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                        
import requests

root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'

class IEAData:
    def get_links(self, url):
        all_links = []
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

        for li in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
           all_links.append(root_url + li.find('a').get('href'))
        return all_links

iea_obj = IEAData()
yearLinks = iea_obj.get_links(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')

for url in yearLinks:
    links = iea_obj.get_links(url)
    print(url, links)
```

This would give you output starting:

```
https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/ ['https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0118/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0218/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0318/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0418/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0518/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0618/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0718/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0818/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/1018/']
https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/ ['https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0117/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0217/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0317/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0417/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0517/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0617/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0717/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0817/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/0917/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/1017/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/1117/', 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2017/1217/']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm still learning and trying to understand how classes and whatnot all work together. But  gave it a shot (that's how we learn, right?)

Not sure if this is what you're looking for as your output. I changed 2 things and was able to put all the links from within the yearLinks into a list. Note that it'll also include the PDF links as well as the months links that I think you wanted. If you don't want those PDF links, and exclusively the months, then just don't include the pdf.

So here's the code I did it with, and maybe you can use that to fit into how you have it structured.

```
root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'


class IEAData:

    def get_links(self, url):

       all_links = []
       page = requests.get(url)
       soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
       for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
           all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
       return all_links
       #print(all_links)


iea_obj = IEAData()
yearLinks = iea_obj.get_links(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')

reportLinks = []

for url in yearLinks:
    links = iea_obj.get_links(url)

    # uncomment line below if you do not want the .pdf links
    #links = [ x for x in links if ".pdf" not in x ]
    reportLinks += links
```